# TAD Lista Método Ordenação em Ordem Alfabética

Tags: c#, lista, classificação, lista-encadeada

Este é o primeiro tópico que estou postando, gostaria que me ajudassem nesse problema.

O problema se baseia em ordenar dados inseridos numa Lista Dinâmica (C#) de acordo com nome (ordem Alfabética). Como é um exercício de facul o professor pede que implementemos a TAD Lista assim como todos seus métodos. A seguir tem um pouco do método de ordenação que fiz:

```
public void ordenaAlfabetica()
        {
            Celula temp1 = Inicio.prox;
            Celula temp2 = temp1.prox; //temp1 assumi o valor próximo à temp
            string nome1; //'nome1' assumi o valor do dado nome da primeira temp em MAIÚSCULO
            string nome2; //'nome2' assumi o valor do dado nome da segunda temp em MAIÚSCULO

            Dados aux = new Dados();
            int a = 0;
            int b = 0;
            int i = 0;

            //inicio da repetição 
            while (temp1 != null && temp2 != null) 
            {
                nome1 = temp1.dados.nome.ToUpper(); //'nome1' assumi o valor do dado nome da primeira temp em MAIÚSCULO
                nome2 = temp2.dados.nome.ToUpper(); //'nome2' assumi o valor do dado nome da segunda temp em MAIÚSCULO

                a = nome1[0]; //'a' assumi o valor em ASCII do primeiro caractere de 'nome1'
                b = nome2[0]; //'b' assumi o valor em ASCII do primeiro caractere de 'nome2'

                while(temp2 != null)
                {
                    nome2 = temp2.dados.nome.ToUpper(); //nome2 assumi o valor do nome da temp

                    a = nome1[0]; //'a' assumi o valor em ASCII do primeiro caractere de 'nome1'
                    b = nome2[0]; //'b' assumi o valor em ASCII do primeiro caractere de 'nome2'

                    while (a == b)  //roda enquanto as letras das palavras forem iguais ou 'i' atigir o tamanho da palavra
                    {
                        if (i == nome1.Length - 1 && i == nome2.Length - 1)
                        {
                            i = 0;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (i < nome1.Length || i < nome2.Length)
                        {
                            i++;
                            a = nome1[i]; //'a' assumi o valor em ASCII do proximo caractere de 'nome1'
                            b = nome2[i]; //'b' assumi o valor em ASCII do proximo caractere de 'nome2'
                        }
                    }

                    if (a > b)
                    {
                        aux = temp1.dados;
                        temp1.dados = temp2.dados;
                        temp2.dados = aux;
                    }

                    temp2 = temp2.prox;
                } 

                temp1 = temp1.prox;
                temp2 = temp1.prox;
            } 
        }
```

Os dados inseridos dentro de cada uma das células é de uma classe Dados que contem encapsulados o Nome e um Código.

> A ideia que estava tentando fazer é caso as primeiras letras da palavra se repita, o terceiro `WHILE` faça com que passe para próxima letra.

O exemplo que estou testando é o seguinte, onde são inseridos nesta ordem:

```
"deise"; 4;
"beatriz"; 2;
"carlos"; 3;
"abcade"; 1;
```

E a saída que deveria ser em ordem alfabética esta da seguinte forma:

```
"abcade"; 1;
"carlos"; 3;
"beatriz"; 2;
"deise"; 4;
```

Alguém teria alguma ideia de onde se encontra o erro??